# ng click not working on jquery append / how to directive dynamic tags

Tags: php, angularjs

first of all i really cant get/understand the use of directive in dynamic way like after button submit then append in particular div.

in result i used jquery in appending elements in angular. my problem is ng-click is not binding on appended elements

below is my code for controller and draw function of my element

VIEW

```
<div class="box" ng-controller="addWorkOrder">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                  New Work Load
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="add_wl" ng-model="addwo_title" placeholder="Add Work Load">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group" id="add_wl_div" style="display:none">
                    <button type="" class="btn bg-olive pull-right" ng-click="click_addwo()">Add</button>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
              </div><!-- /.box -->
```

Angular Controller

```
app.controller('addWorkOrder',['$scope','$rootScope','$http','$compile',function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$compile){
    $scope.$watch('project_id',function(){
            $scope.click_addwo = function(){
                $http.post(base_url+'ajax/add_workorder',{proj_id:$rootScope.project_id,wo_title:$scope.addwo_title})
                .then(function(response){
                    if(response.data.success == 0){
                        alert(response.data.msg);
                    }else{

                        draw_workorder({
                            wo_id : response.data.data,
                            wo_title : $scope.addwo_title
                        });
                        $scope.addwo_title = "";
                    }
                });
            }       
        });
}]);
```

lastly my function draw_workorder() to be called upon success of submit button

```
function draw_workorder(data){
    // workorder card view
    l = '<tr data-id="'+ data.wo_id +'" style="display:none;">'+
            '<td style="width:30px"></td>'+
            '<td class="mailbox-name"><a href="read-mail.html" ng-click="wmodal('+ data.wo_id +')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">'+ data.wo_title +'</a></td>'+
            '<td class="mailbox-subject"><span class="badge bg-red">pending</span></td>'+
            '<td class="mailbox-attachment"></td>'+
            '<td class="mailbox-date" data-livestamp="'+ new Date().toLocaleString() +'"></td>'+
        '</tr>'; 
    $(l).prependTo('#wo_container').fadeIn();
}
```

anyone can teach me how to properly append/prepend elements using directives after http service ins controller is much appreciated

once again im sorry for being newbie in angular. i tried my best to read Angular Directive documentation and it seems other examples they give is so complicated for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you need to do is to let Angular know, that your element actually has directives. This can be achieved by using $compile service, here, I simplified your example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexEmashev/u3Lxmncm/)

```
app.controller('addWorkOrder', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$compile',
  function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $compile) {

  $scope.click_addwo = function() {
    l = '<button type="" ng-click="attachedFunct()">Click Me!</button>';
    $('#wo_container').append($compile(l)($scope));
  };

  // Function that will be used by dynamically added element.
  $scope.attachedFunct = function() {
    alert('Clicked attached function');
  };
 }
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ng-click is not working because you need to compile the html before you append it to some element.

```
var $compile = ...; // injected into your code
var scope = ...;
var parent = ...; // DOM element where the compiled template can be appended

var html = '<div ng-bind="exp"></div>';

// Step 1: parse HTML into DOM element
var template = angular.element(html);

// Step 2: compile the template
var linkFn = $compile(template);

// Step 3: link the compiled template with the scope.
var element = linkFn(scope);

// Step 4: Append to DOM (optional)
parent.appendChild(element);
```

> for more info please go to this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)